# How to set my database back to the initial values

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a Database with a Table named Employees with fields:

1. name
2. dept
3. isPresent
4. Hours

I made an API which changes the isPresent and Hours value of the employees.

Now I want to create a button which resets the value of all the employees to the initial values.

How to achieve that in web api C#?

Comment: If it's only those two values, the easiest solution would be to create a backup column and store the old data if you update the values - however that's not the nicest way. Otherwise you'd have to mirror the table or implement a LOG table which stores the old values as history.

Comment: All the rows in the table will have same initial values?

Comment: it would be better if you explained exactly what you are trying to achieve and why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to retain the original data you should create a second table called `initialEmployees` that is a duplicate of `Employees` before any changes are made.

Copy all initial values into this duplicate table as well as your real table.
When ever you add a new row to `Employees` you want to also add that row to `initialEmployees`.

Then when you press the reset value button it will copy the data from the `initialEmployees` table to the 'Employees' table in the row you choose.

If your name field is a unique identifier you can use this to keep track what row in `initialEmployees` is connected to the row `Employees`. Otherwise I would add a ID column to both of the tables that way they can always be connected easily.